# Problem with IDictionary<Complex Key, Complex Value>.Remove() implementation

Tags: c#

Hi I don't understand why this code doesn't work - it don't remove key; I still get "2" on output.

```
Bencode.BencodeDict d = new myTorrent.Bencode.BencodeDict();
d.Dict.Add(new Bencode.BencodeString("info"), new Bencode.BencodeString("1"));
d.Dict.Add(new Bencode.BencodeString("info2"), new Bencode.BencodeString("2"));
d.Dict.Add(new Bencode.BencodeString("info3"), new Bencode.BencodeString("3"));

d.Remove(new Bencode.BencodeString("info2"));
Bencode.BencodeVariable s1;
s1 = d[new Bencode.BencodeString("info2")];
if (s1 != null)
   Console.WriteLine(System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(s1.Encode()));
```

My BencodeDict and BencodeString

```
namespace myTorrent.Bencode
{
   class BencodeDict : BencodeVariable, IDictionary<BencodeString, BencodeVariable>
   {
      private Dictionary<BencodeString, BencodeVariable> dict;

      public BencodeDict() {
         this.dict = new Dictionary<BencodeString,BencodeVariable>();
      }

      protected override void InternalDecode(BinaryReader data) { /*...*/ }
      public override long ByteLength() { /*...*/ }    
      public override byte[] Encode() { /*...*/ }

      //#region Overridden Methods
        public override bool Equals(object ob)
        {
            if (ob == null)
               return false;

            BencodeDict y = ob as BencodeDict;
            if (this.dict.Count != y.dict.Count)
                return false;

            BencodeVariable val;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<BencodeString, BencodeVariable> keypair in this.dict)
            {
                if (!y.TryGetValue(keypair.Key, out val))
                    return false;

                if (!keypair.Value.Equals(val))
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            int result = 0;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<BencodeString, BencodeVariable> keypair in this.dict)
            {
                result ^= keypair.Key.GetHashCode();
                result ^= keypair.Value.GetHashCode();
            }
            return result;
        }

        #region IDictionary and IList methods
        public void Add(BencodeString key, BencodeVariable value)
        {
            this.dict.Add(key, value);
        }

        public void Add(KeyValuePair<BencodeString, BencodeVariable> item)
        {
            this.dict.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
        public void Clear()
        {
            this.dict.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<BencodeString, BencodeVariable> item)
        {  
            if (!this.dict.ContainsKey(item.Key))
                return false;

            return this.dict[item.Key].Equals(item.Value);
        }

        public bool ContainsKey(BencodeString key)
        {
            foreach(KeyValuePair<BencodeString, BencodeVariable> pair in this.dict) {
               if (pair.Key.Equals(key))
                  return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<BencodeString, BencodeVariable>[] array, int arrayIndex) { /*...*/ }
        public int Count
        {
            get { return this.dict.Count; }
        }

        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public bool Remove(BencodeString key)
        {

            return this.dict.Remove(key);
        }

        public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<BencodeString, BencodeVariable> item)
        {
            return this.dict.Remove(item.Key);
        }

        public bool TryGetValue(BencodeString key, out BencodeVariable value)
        {
           foreach(KeyValuePair<BencodeString, BencodeVariable> pair in this.dict)
              if ( pair.Key.Equals(key) ) {
                 value = pair.Value;
                 return true;
              }
           value = null;
           return false;
        }

        public BencodeVariable this[BencodeString key]
        {  
            get {
                foreach(KeyValuePair<BencodeString, BencodeVariable> pair in this.dict)
                     if ( pair.Key.Equals(key) )
                     return pair.Value;
                return null;
            }
            set { this.dict[key] = value; }
        }

        public ICollection<BencodeString> Keys
        {
            get { return this.dict.Keys; }
        }

        public ICollection<BencodeVariable> Values
        {
            get { return this.dict.Values; }
        }

        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<BencodeString, BencodeVariable>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.dict.GetEnumerator();
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.dict.GetEnumerator();
        }
        #endregion
   }
}


   class BencodeString : BencodeVariable
      {
         private byte[] str;

         public BencodeString() {
            this.str = null;
         }

         public BencodeString(string str) {
            this.str = encoding.GetBytes(str);
         }

         public override bool Equals(object ob)
         {
            if (ob == null)
               return false;

            BencodeString y = ob as BencodeString;

            return (encoding.GetString(this.str) == encoding.GetString(y.str));
         }

         public override int GetHashCode()
         {

            return this.str.GetHashCode();
         }
      }
```

Comment: You have some complicated .Equals logic there, why don't you set a breakpoint at the top of that method and see where things are going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very important that values that are Equal also produce the same hash code.  An obvious (but not necessarily efficient) workaround is this:

```
     public override int GetHashCode()
     {
         return encoding.GetString(this.str).GetHashCode();
     }
```

Making strings not behave as Unicode strings internally is a a code smell but possibly intentional here.  It is normally applied at the outer interface.  Your implementation would allow for the encoding to change after the string is read.  But a really serious problem with that is that the dictionary is no longer valid when that happens.  You won't be able to find keys back.

Comment: +1 in that it's the right approach in the case where unequal byte arrays which still decode to the same string (e.g. by having invalid byte sequences decoded to "?") should be treated the same way. If the byte arrays really should be equal, then it would be better to check the arrays themselves for equality (as per my edit).

Answer (score 2):

You're relying on `byte[].GetHashCode()` doing something desirable. It won't. Arrays don't implement equality or hash operations - you'll get the default (identity) behaviour.

Rewrite your `GetHashCode` method as something like this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int result = 17;
    foreach (byte b in str)
    {
        result = result * 31 + b;
    }
    return result;
}
```

(Also it's not clear what `encoding` is, but that's a different matter.)

Note that your `Equals` override will also throw a `NullReferenceException` if `ob` is a non-null reference, but not to a `BencodeString`.

EDIT: Assuming you're actually wanting to check for the byte arrays being the same, I wouldn't call `Encoding.GetString` in your equality check. There's no point. Just check the byte array contents directly. Something like this is a reasonable byte array equality check - although I'd generally prefer to write a generic equivalent:

```
private static bool ArraysEqual(byte[] x, byte[] y)
{
    if (x == y)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (x == null || y == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (x.Length != y.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
    {
        if (x[i] != y[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you *do* want to check whether two byte arrays are decoded to equal strings, then you should use `Encoding.GetString` in both places... but that would rarely be an appropriate thing to do, IMO.

Mind you, it's not clear why you've got your own string-like class to start with. There are all kinds of potential problems here... unequal encodings, null references etc.

Comment: This is not correct.  Two of these strings could be equal after the encoding is applied.  But won't generate the same hash code with your algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wondering about that, but didn't check -_-

Comment: Well, you don't have to, you already got the answer mark.  Oh dear.

Comment: @Hans: This is the reason the code wasn't working with the data given. It's the most significant way in which the code is broken.